# Using Triggers to insert a value or spit out an error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger that fires before an insert on ENROLLMENT table, which is related to the COURSE_SECTION table through C_SEC_ID. The trigger fires when a new enrollment is added. Before it can insert a record, it looks on the MAX_ENRL and CURR_ENRL columns of the COURSE_SECTION table and checks it, if the condition is met (i.e CURR_ENRL < MAX_ENRL), the insertion is done, if not it fires an error.

This is what I've done so far, but I do not know how to just check for the right C_SEC_ID concerned.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_INCRE_ENRL_NUM
BEFORE INSERT ON ENROLLMENT 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF COURSE_SECTION.CURR_ENRL < COURSE_SECTION.MAX_ENRL THEN
COURSE_SECTION.CURR_ENRL := COURSE_SECTION.CURR_ENRL + 1;
ELSE RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005, 'Failure in trigger TRG_INCR_ENRL_NUM: 
Max Enrollment reached.');
END IF;
NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the comparison in a select query to `COURSE_SECTION` with a case and using the `:NEW.c_sec_id` column. `UPDATE` the table if condition is true else raise error. This assumes that your **course_section** table will always have **one** row for a given `c_sec_id`, if not you may have to handle `no_data_found` or use `MAX`, `MIN` in your select query.

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER trg_incre_enrl_num 
BEFORE INSERT ON enrollment 
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE v_condition PLS_INTEGER := 0; 

BEGIN 
  SELECT 
         CASE 
                WHEN curr_enrl < max_enrl 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
         END 
   INTO   v_condition 
  FROM   course_section 
 WHERE  c_sec_id = :NEW.c_sec_id; 

  IF v_condition = 1 THEN 
    UPDATE course_section 
    SET    curr_enrl = curr_enrl + 1; --increment the value in table.

  ELSE 
    raise_application_error(-20005, 'Failure in trigger TRG_INCR_ENRL_NUM: Max Enrollment reached.'); 
  END IF; 
END;
/
```

Comment: It still gave some errors, or is it just the syntax.

Comment: @RyanThompson : Fixed. check now